# Given a triangle $\triangle ABC$, which fulfills the equations $6\cos{A}+2\cos{B}=7$ and $6\sin{A}-2\sin{B}=\sqrt{3}$, find the value of $\angle C$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, contest-math, problem-solving

Given a triangle $\triangle ABC$, which fulfills the equations $6\cos{A}+2\cos{B}=7$ and $6\sin{A}-2\sin{B}=\sqrt{3}$, find the value of $\angle C$.

I though of solving it as follows:

$36\cos^2{A}+24\cos{B}\cos{A}+4\cos^2{B}=49$

$36\sin^2{A}-24\sin{B}\sin{A}+4\sin^2{B}=3$

Hence $12=24(\cos{A}\cos{B}-\sin{B}\sin{A})$

And I got stuck here. I then tried putting in different values for $\angle A, \angle B$ to find a pair that works, but I couldn't find one. Could you please explain to me how to solve the question?

Comment: That $13$ should be a $12$, so $\cos(A+B)=\tfrac12$.

Comment: @J.G. you're right, thanks a lot for picking me up on the error

Comment: It should be $6 \sin A- 2\sin B=\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Thank you too @ZAhmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

You have done the hard work!

Use $\cos(A+B)$ formula

Finally use

$$\cos(A+B)=\cos(\pi-C)=?$$

Comment: Nice one thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

$6\cos{A}+2\cos{B}=7$ and $6\sin{A}-2\sin{B}=\sqrt{3}$
Squaring and adding these two equations, we get
$$36(\sin^2 A+\cos^2 A)+4(\cos^2 B+\sin^2 b)+24(\cos A \cos B-\sin A \sin B)=52$$
$$\implies 36+4+24\sin (A+B)=52 \implies \cos(A+B)=1/2=-\cos C \implies C= 2\pi/3$$